# XSSF cookie stealer not working

Tags: xss, metasploit

I am playing with XSSF with Metasploit and attacking Mutilldae(security 0). I was able to get the generic XSS inject working. The inject was added to the Mutilldae blog. However, when I try to get the cookie stealer to work the program just sits there with no success.

[image]

I have tried it on 3 devices with Chrome and Firefox with no luck. Any ideas why this could be happening?